# Selenium search in google, then scan page if keyword exists

Tags: windows, selenium, anaconda, python-3.6

**1.**
I'm using Selenium to search for **"sage release dates"** in google.

**2.**
Then I want to scan the entire results page if my search word **"release date"** exists in the results.

I'm reusing this search pattern code from a previous project of mine but that one used urllib.  So I had to adjust the search pattern code slightly.  But it doesn't do what I want.  I'm stuck.  Can somebody point me in the right direction?

```js
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import re

#   Version Alpha 3
#_______________________________________________________________________________

browser = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\Selenium_Drivers\chromedriver.exe")
browser.get('http://www.google.com')

input_element = browser.find_element_by_name('q')
input_element.send_keys('sage release dates')
# input_element.send_keys('Wolters Kluwer release dates')
input_element.submit()

'''
RESULTS_LOCATOR = '//div/h3/a'

WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, RESULTS_LOCATOR)))

page1_results = browser.find_elements(By.XPATH, RESULTS_LOCATOR)
'''

page1_results = browser.find_elements_by_class_name('med')

for item in page1_results:
    print(item.text)

#..................................................

keywords = ['release date']

# sequence = page1_results.decode('utf-8', 'ignore')
sequence = page1_results

for k in keywords:
    pattern = '(?i)' + k
    keyword = re.search(pattern, str(sequence))
    if keyword:
        # print(keyword.group(0))
        print('k-1')
        print(k)
        print(keyword)
    else:
        print('k-2')
        print('-')
        print(k)
        print(keyword)




#..................................................
# browser.quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply create an intelligent xpath to find if search results have elements with keyword('sage release dates') text. For example, check if entire results page has one of the following texts or any of the below:

- result elements with text 'sage'
- result elements with text 'sage release'
- result elements with text 'release dates'

This way you can improve your search. However, you modify the xpath if you dont want additional filters.

If you want results which has text 'sage release dates', use below xpath:

`//*[contains(text(), 'sage release dates')]`

If you want results with text 'release dates' only, use below xpath:

`//*[contains(text(), 'release dates')]`

Sample code snippet in Python:

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver.get('http://www.google.com')
elem = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
elem.send_keys("sage release dates")
elem.submit()

allResults = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'sage release dates') or contains(text(), 'sage') or contains(text(), 'release') or contains(text(), 'sage release')]")
releaseDateResults = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//*[contains(text(), 'release date')]")

print len(allResults)
print len(releaseDateResults)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: A follow-up question.  How can I make my xpath searches case insensitive?
.<br>
`all_results = browser.find_elements_by_xpath(
"//*[contains(text(), 'release date') or contains(text(), 'SAGE Release')]")`
.<br>
`for item in all_results:
    print(item.text)`

Comment: For case sensitive query, you can use translate function. For the xpath:
//*[contains(text(), 'release date') or contains(text(), 'SAGE Release')] to
//*[contains(text(), 'release date') or contains(text(),translate('release date', 'relasdt','RELASDT')) or contains(text(), 'SAGE Release') or contains(text(), translate('SAGE Release','sagerl', 'SAGERL'))]